# How to run a parameterized job from a pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a job that has N (N representing the number of choice parameters there is) choice parameters. I want to pass each choice parameter to a pipeline. The pipeline needs to build the job with each choice parameter (e.g. Name of parameter is 'Project' with choices {A,B,C}. Pipeline needs to build the job for every choice provided in the project parameter).

I have researched endlessly on google/stackoverflow and haven't come up with a good solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

There is quite some fiddling that needs to be done in order to get the choices from another job. It could be easier to just hard code them. If you want to access it dynamically you could do something like this:

```
def choices = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("myJob")
                 .getProperty(hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty)
                 .getParameterDefinition("parameterName").getChoices()

choices.each{choice ->
    build job: "myJob", parameters: [string(name: "parameterName", value: choice)] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So let's say the job with the choices is pipeline B and the one calling it with all the options is A.

In job A you would either hardcode the different options or just have a textfield parameter where you can enter the desired choices. Somewhere in your pipeline (within a `script`-block if you use declarative style) you need to do something like this:

```
//for every selected choice
params.choices.split("\n").each{ choice ->
     build job: "myJob", parameters: [string(name: "nameOfChoiceParam", value: choice)]
}
```

As you can see, internally choice params are nothing more than string parameters.

Edit:

If you want to build this in parallel you need to use scripted pipelines (I think, maybe it also works in declarative ones). The `parallel` function expects a `Map<String, Closure>` and there are many ways to generate it, but one would be:

```
def steps = params.choices.split("\n").collectEntries{ choice ->
    [(choice): {
        build job: "myJob", parameters: [string(name: "nameOfChoiceParam", value: choice)] 
    }]
}
parallel steps
```

If you want to do this for all available nodes, you need to generate a list of all the possibilities first (the `combiniations` would help) or you could use the good old nested for loop.

When there are 30 choices, you might not gain as much through parallelization and there are a lot of factors (how many executers are there per node, etc.). It would be faster in general to just put the code there directly instead of launching a separate pipeline, especially if we are talking about `choices * nodes = 30 * 4 = 120` executions.

Comment: Let's say I want to run pipeline B (pipeline with all of the choices) in pipeline A but in parallel (e.g. pipeline B contains 30 different choices and I want to run pipeline A with all 30 choices at once from pipeline B on 4 different nodes). How would I accomplish this?

Comment: I am getting the following error... "WorkflowScript: 19: Expected a step @ line 19, column 23. def action = params.choices.collectEntries{ choice ->

Comment: You have to wrap it inside a script block `script { ... } `

Comment: I keep getting a null pointer exception "Cannot invoke method split() on null object"

Comment: Make sure you use `params.<your parameter>`. Maybe just println this. Null in this context indicates a wrong parameter name

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned but still running into some issues. When I build the pipeline, I notice that it mentions for me to "build the pipeline with parameters"? I need the pipeline to just build each choice from the choice parameter I have without having to select a value from the dropdown list each time I build (So basically just building with each choice and not having to manually go through and select the choice after each build.)

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your question. I added another answer to address this. Honestly the easiest thing would be to just hardcode the choices in the other pipeline

Comment: Is there any possible way to build the pipeline without having to select from the parameters dropdown menu every time I build? (e.g. I have a parameter with name param1 with choices {A, B, C, D}). These choices are hardcoded (I found it easier to do hardcode them like you mentioned). Now I need the pipeline to build with choices A,B,C,D in one single build (without having to go back and select each choice from the dropdown). The pipeline would build all choices {A,B,C,D} in a single build. Is this possible? Currently, this is not being accomplished with our implementation.

Comment: so sometimes you want to build all, and sometimes just one/ a few? What is more frequent, selecting all or selecting just some?

Comment: I want to build all every time in a single build.

Comment: So is there even a reason for two pipelines or could it be just one?

Comment: There is a job and a single pipeline that builds the job. There isn't two pipelines. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: oh I see, so one freestyle job triggered multiple times with one pipeline?

Comment: yes exactly. It is a freestyle job that contains a parameter that has multiple choices. I need that freestyle job to build once via the other pipeline. That pipeline needs to run once and in that single run it needs to build all of the different choices.